# How to display same text data on every wordpress page using plugin

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-hook

I want to print "Hello World" after page title to every wordpress page by using plugin. I can do it from page.php in theme folder, but I want to do it using plugin.
Thank  you in advance.

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name:  Display Data
Plugin URI:   https://rb.com
Description:  My Plugin Dev.
Version:      0.1
Author:       RB
*/
function printData()
{
  if(THIS IS A PAGE)
  {
    echo "Hello World";
  }
  else
  {
    echo "This is not a Page";
  }
}
add_action('DONT KNOW WHAT SHOULD BE HERE','printData');
?>
```

Comment: you want after `<title></title>`?

Answer (score 0):

Where you need print data? Head title ()? Content title?

an example in header for every Page:

```
function printData($title)
{
  if(is_page())
  {
    $title .= " Hello World";
  }
  else
  {
    $title .= " This is not a Page";
  }

  return $title;
}
add_filter('wp_title','printData');
```

For content title:

```
function printData($title)
{
  if(is_page())
  {
    $title .= " Hello World";
  }
  else
  {
    $title .= " This is not a Page";
  }

  return $title;
}
add_filter('the_title','printData');
```

Comment: I want to print the data after content title. Not along with content title.

Comment: Yes. My example printing text after title. you can use HTML tags, if you want or need. If your title is wrapped in some HTML tags and you wanna print text after this html - use filters or actions. Create `do_action()` after your title and write hooks. But if you cant create hooks in theme folders and needed print data after title html - you will can`t print your data without hook or theme editing.

Comment: The problem with using `the_title` is that it adds the text to the title text, but the HTML that surrounds the title is almost always output in the theme files. You should, instead, filter `the_content` - https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content

Comment: Whit the_content might be the same problem. Impossible to write universal solution for all themes and templates. We need see you template structure. And we can answer correctly.